# Build Raster Attribute Table from .tif with pixel type of float or double?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster-attribute-table

I have a raster with the extension .tif. It's a subset of 87x87 pixel with values from some 6,66 to -4,27. If I right click on it there is no Attribute Table available. However, I can change the Symbology to Unique, Streched, Classified or Discrete Color and also classify manually, everything just fine. However, I need this attribute table, as I want to calculate the statistics of the values (not only the simple like mean and min, i got those, but a bit more advanced). 
The ArcGIS help site ('Build Raster Attribute Table (Data Management)') mentions, that: 'It is not possible to build a raster attribute table for a raster dataset that has a pixel type of floating point or double precision.' 
My values, however, ARE 32bit floating point. Does any of you have a clue what I can do?

Answer (score 5):

The solution to this problem is to multiple your grid by 100 to move the digits to the left of the decimal point. I suggest 100 as your example are to 2 decimal places, if it were 3 then you multiple by 1000. After the multiplication you may need to run your dataset through the [INT](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000008z000000) tool to make sure it is converted to an integer grid.

Do your analysis then divide by 100.

Comment: +1 but I think a tif to grid conversion step needs to be added at the beginning of this procedure.

Comment: @PolyGeo no conversion required. ArcGIS 10+ treats tifs as any other type of raster. It uses GDAL 'under the hood' now for raster reading so you can even drop GDAL VRTs into the ArcMap TOC.

Comment: Maybe I don't get the obvious, but isn't PolyGeo right? I have a tif which has no attribute table, so before I can multiply the values by e.g. 100 I need at least some kind of table.

Thanks for editing and answering.

Comment: @Tatue, no you don't need a table before you can do any  arithmetic (i.e multiply  by 100) on a raster as you would use the [raster calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm) to perform the arithmetic, not the [field calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/).