# Attribute Table missing After Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I want to remove zero value pixels from MODIS LST raster images and apply a moving window that can only substitute the missing values and leave the other original values with out alteration.  I have tried this  raster Calculator command from ([Filling NoData gaps in raster using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136075/filling-nodata-gaps-in-raster-using-arcgis-desktop/136187#136187?newreg=9ec9d92a5d0c4963ab200440757bfc74))

```
Con(IsNull("raster"),FocalStatistics("raster",NbrRectangle(5,5,"CELL"),"MEAN"),"raster")
```

However the resulting raster image does not have attribute table. Since I have many raster images I want to do this work in ModelBuilder, this is just a process to check before going to ModelBuilder. Some of the rasters have many zero values(missing values) and I am not sure whether this affects the focal statistics or not.

What should I do?

Comment: That will return a floating point raster which cannot have an attribute table. If you really need an attribute table you will need to convert to an integer data type raster. See this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78109/70980